# Access shared mailbox via microsoft graph

Tags: api, graph, office365

Is it possible to access a shared mailbox via microsoft graph api v2?

In the documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations
there is always "me" used in the URLs.

How can i access a shared mailbox via graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing "me" with "users('emailadress-of-the-sharedmailbox')" ist the solution.